# GROUP BY with SUM() using Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, group-by

I came across similar questions but none of them had a complete example of how to accomplish it.

The SQL query I am trying to translate is this:

```
SELECT date, SUM(amount) FROM Table GROUP BY date;
```

I need help debugging the following piece code (currently the fetchRequest returns nil):

```
entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Table" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSExpressionDescription* ex = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[ex setExpression:[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"@sum.amount"]];
[ex setExpressionResultType:NSDecimalAttributeType];

[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"date", ex, nil]];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"date"]];
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType ];

[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

This is the error:

```
2012-09-28 13:58:46.319 App[12205:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
```

Comment: can you please print the NSLog(@"error: %@", error); output

Comment: It doesn't even get to the NSLog:

2012-09-28 13:58:46.319 App[12205:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Comment: So if I catch the exception, the contents of error is null

Comment: so please fix the "object cannot be nil" exception first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code above needs

```
[ex setName:@"somename"];
```

before executing the fetchRequest.