# ios table with data that is grouped by

Tags: ios, core-data, group-by, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a conceptual sql query that uses group by on a core data table t as follows:

select a, b, sum(c) c_sum from t group by a, b;

Using core data I can run the query (as described in thread [GROUP BY with SUM() using Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637611/group-by-with-sum-using-core-data)). I would like to use NSFetchedResultsController. I tried the following:

1. In my "refresh" operation, I tried to use the fetch request corresponding to the above group by query directly but ran into the problem  "NSFetchedResultsController does not support both change tracking and fetch request's with NSDictionaryResultType".
2. Then I thought of the following. Save the records in the table t. Then run the above query and save the result in another table t1. Tie the nsfetchedresultscontroller to a regular fetch from t1. Unfortunately, in this case, I run into the issue that the group by query does not see anything in the db since the document save operation is asynchronous.
3. To counter the above issue, I tried to save the document right after I did the insert into table t - but then I got the error "This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores.  It cannot perform a save operation."

The obvious alternative is for me to do the group by and sum programmatically and then insert data into t1 but I thought I would ask around here to see if others have any thoughts. Second one that I have not tried yet is to listen to document save notification and then do the insert into t1. Another alternative is to not use nsfetchedresultscontroller - which I would like to avoid.

Thoughts?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**:
OK detecting save notification and then populating t1 from t using the grouped by query works but is not a good solution because:
1. I am the mercy of when the save operation happens
2. Each time the save happens, the table is repopulated which is not a good idea obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I finally figured out how to save the context, i.e. how to successfully do the option 3 without running into the error mentioned. The option 3 involves using UIDocument saveToURL:forSaveOperation:completionHandler: operation. That is what I had tried. But the error I made was that I was creating a new UIManaged Document instance from the same url as the original document instance (whose managed context I had been using).

So, now in my viewWillAppear, I save the document also as a property at the same time I save the managed context property. Then when I run the saveToUrl, I use the property document instance - in this case, I do not get the error "This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores. It cannot perform a save operation."