# How to group by daily date, e.g. DATE(datecolumn), in iOS Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data

I'd like to group by daily date in iOS Core Data. How to make a query like `group by DATE(datecolumn)` as SQLite.

In [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html), it seems DATE() method is not supported.

so, `[request setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"date.datecolumn"]];` didn't work.

Comment: What is the data type of your DateColumn? It should be of DATE data type.

Refer question part of this thread for group by.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637611/group-by-with-sum-using-core-data?rq=1

Comment: yes, the type of datecolumn is DATE data type.